# Centering the TextView's text vertically in relation to its drawableLeft image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have this component:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon" />
```

The image in the drawableLeft attribute is bigger than the font of the text, so I want the text centered vertically in relation to the image. How can I get this effect?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You want "gravity" note this is not to be confused with layout gravity, layout gravity moves the entire textview, while gravity moves the text within the text view.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I previously tried layout_gravity and it didn't work, didn't know about the difference, but now it's ok.

Answer (score 86):

In addition to setting the gravity, this can also help with alignment in some situations by reducing paddings on the top and bottom of the textview, which can be unequal:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Thanks, `android:gravity` in combination with this solved it for me!

Comment: This saved me! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you don't care about text accents, just try `android:includeFontPadding="false"`.This will remove extra top and bottom padding of `TextView`.
As to `android:gravity="center_vertical"`, it has no effect on my code.

Answer (score -1):

You should place both the `Drawable` and the `TextView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and use the [`layout_alignBaseline`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_alignBaseline) attribute on your `TextView`.

You could also place just the two items, `Drawable` and `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` with a `horizontal` orientation and `layout_height="wrap_content"` and use `layout_gravity="center_vertical"` on your `TextView`.

Comment: using android:gravity would be a much cleaner and faster method, though this would give you a bit more flexibility to resize images on the fly, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't want to use the drawableLeft since the icon was to small and I wanted an ImageButton instead. I was messing around with margins until I came upon your answer. Upvoted.